# Macro to match cells across worksheets and then copy and paste relevant cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro that matches values in column A of Sheet("Company"), to those in Column E of "Current". If there is a match, and the cell 28 ("Current") to the right of this is empty, then I want to copy the cell to the right of the respective cell in "Company" and paste it. It should loop through all values in column A of Sheet("Company"). For added difficulty, I'd love if I could implement a kind of ActiveSheet utility, so that I can apply it to other sheets rather than just "Company". Here's what I have...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaster()

InvestorName As String

InvestorName = ActiveCell.Value

With Sheets("Current")

For i = 11 To 500:
    If i = InvestorName And Cells(i, 27) = 0 Then
        Sheets("Company").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Copy          
        Sheets("Current").Cells(i, 28).PasteSpecial                
Next i

End Sub
```

First shows the Current Sheet, and the second image is an example of one of the Company sheets I want to copy from.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck or what kind of error do you encounter?

Comment: you are missing here the `End If` to `If i = InvestorName And Cells(i, 27) = 0 Then` ? also the `With Sheets("Current")` ?

Comment: @user6701007 please share a sample of your data in both worksheets, and what is the desired result of the code should be ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Is there an easy way to share a worksheet? or attach it to my post?

Comment: @user6701007 you can just print screen the worksheet and add it as an image. Did you see my comment above ? are you missing `End If` and `End With`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given, I think this is what you are after. Please double check that I chose the right columns, it was difficult to guess what you were referring to without data to look at.

```
Sub StackExchangeVlookup()

Dim Company As Worksheet
Dim Current As Worksheet

'set worksheets with the names of the sheets to compare
Set Company = Sheets("Company")
Set Current = Sheets("Current")

Dim myRange As range
Dim myCell As range
'Set the range to the column you want to replace empty cells in. I think I counted
'correctly, but maybe not. If AF is not correct, will also need to change the 32
Set myRange = range("AF1", Cells(Rows.count, 32).End(xlUp))

'if the cell is empty in the column AF (or whichever is the one you want, then use
'the VLOOKUP function.
For Each myCell In myRange
    If Len(myCell) = 0 Then
    'VLOOKUP will get the cell in column E of the row of the blank space in AF, compare
    'it to Column A in Company, and then return the value to the right of the cell found
    'in the Company sheet.
        myCell.Value = _
    "=VLOOKUP(" & Current.Name & "!E" & myCell.Row & "," & Company.Name & "!A:B, 2, FALSE)"
    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```